CSS fade works in emulation on desktop, not on actual mobile device
I have created the following mask and tested it by means of the desktop browser's mobile device emulation (from the Developer Tools in Firefox):
    .Main
    {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        --mask: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) calc(100% - 250px), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%)
                center / cover
                repeat-x;
        -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
        mask: var(--mask);
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

In the preview, this ensures that the bottom edge of .Main's content fades out if it is less than 250 pixels from the bottom of the view (or, indeed, extends below the bottom edge of the view).

But the device emulation is not perfect, and this doesn't seem to be doing anything when I browse to it from an Android device.

Not sure how to debug/fix this. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? :-P
